# What is the difference between dpois,rpois and ppois in R?

Tags: r, data-science

**Not able to understand where which one should be used.**

Comment: What about reading `?dpois` `?rpois` and `?ppois`?

Comment: @JilberUrbina: those all direct to the same web page :-)  (If OP doesn't understand where to use them, the manual page probably won't help) Can you give us some context? What are you trying to achieve? Do you know the underlying concepts of probability distribution function (`dpois`), random deviate (`rpois`), and cumulative distribution function (`ppois`) ?

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed. I found it perfectly straightforward and would have liked a simple and comprehensible answer. This website does the job: https://www.statology.org/dpois-ppois-qpois-rpois-r/

Answer (score 9):

**dpois** is the **Probability Density Function** (of the Poisson distribution). This means the probability that the random variable will be within some range

**ppois** is the **Cumulative Probability Function**. This means the probability that the random variable will be lower than or equal to a value.

**rpois** is a function that randomly generates values from that distribution

More info:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Poisson.html
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-probability-density-function-probability-mass-function-and-probability-distribution-function
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: as your Quora link points out, for discrete distributions we don't technically look at a probability **density** function, but a probability mass function (or maybe call it a probability *distribution* function) ...